# How to add documents t0 list index content in Cloud-based ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can access /deployments end point
(https://api.elastic-cloud.com/api/v1/deployments)

but if I a trying
https://api.elastic-cloud.com/api/v1/_cat/indicies
or
https://api.elastic-cloud.com/api/v1/indicies
or
https://api.elastic-cloud.com/api/v1/_cat/indicies/products
(product index exists and this works form the console)

I am getting
{
"ok": false,
"message": "The requested resource could not be found."
}